# When did the term "Electronics" come into common use

Tags: terminology

I know from watching old movies that in the U.S., for a time at the dawn of the vacuum tube era, the term "radio" was used to refer to the field of electronics (in addition to the medium of broadcast audio, of course).  When did the term "electronics" take over?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology.

Answer (score 1):

Slander! Also, this is probably better in the English Stack Exchange... Anyway Electricity and Electronics and similar works take the root word *Elektron* in Greek, and apply latin-style adjustments to the end of the word. The "onics" is a suffix of the noun that denote a body of facts, knowledge, or principles. There are many words with this ending.

Many non-english languages such as German use the same word too, like "Elektrik" usually with lots of "k"s in there for good measure. Not sure about the yankees, but i'm certain that every other place has referred to electronics as such, since the dawn of electronics.

Comment: I think the Yankees used Radiologisticographicology.

Comment: That's very comprehensive of them @Majenko. Also what happened to the "Not google" suffix?? lol

Comment: It's what's called an Americanisationalism: *"The Americanisationalism of English vocabularistic units empowers the yankydoodledandies to verbalize in a much extensivelized impressionistically technicalistically manner."* :)  And I decided that I was Google after all.

Comment: @Majenko well half of my answer was from Google and less than 5 minutes of reading.. The Google-Fu is strong with us?

Comment: I thought I felt a tingle down my Ethernet cable while you came up with your answer...

Comment: Thanks again for your endless pool of knowledge, and such easy access @Majenko

Comment: I get the etymology of "electronics".  I just thought the field was called "radio" for good bit of time until it fell out of favor.  Possibly I saw a bad old movie.

Comment: @CarlRaymond never trust movies, who knows what sick things the directors do to them. Look at what Peter Jackson did to Lord of the Rings.